# How to recover deleted "dpkg" directory?

Tags: dpkg

Unfortunately I've deleted **dpkg** directory while removing the lock. By mistake I typed

```
root@sam:~$ rm -r /var/lib/dpkg
```

Now when I am trying to install/uninstall packages it shows me following error.

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (2: No such file or directory)
```

What should I do now?

Comment: Have you tried *copying* (Try to not delete them) the files from a Ubuntu Live CD into the system itself as Superuser??

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Using root and recursive rm (`rm -r`) is a recipe for disasters, don't do it. The files and directories that were deleted are as follows:

```
ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/
total 9964
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 nov 28 11:18 alternatives
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      11 sep 18 14:08 arch
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2573807 nov 28 11:18 available
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2561322 nov 28 10:25 available-old
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       8 abr 24  2013 cmethopt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     538 sep 25 17:24 diversions
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     457 sep 25 17:24 diversions-old
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  483328 nov 28 11:17 info
-rw-r----- 1 root root       0 nov 28 11:18 lock
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 mar 22  2013 parts
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     135 abr 24  2013 statoverride
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2269113 nov 28 11:18 status
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2268870 nov 28 11:18 status-old
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 nov 28 11:18 triggers
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 nov 28 11:18 updates
```

You removed 5 directories, the status file, etc. So, lets try to fix the stuff. First, create the directory:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/dpkg/{alternatives,info,parts,triggers,updates}
```

Recover some backups:

```
sudo cp /var/backups/dpkg.status.0 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Check if dpkg is working:

```
apt-get download dpkg
sudo dpkg -i dpkg*.deb
```

If everything is "ok" then repair your base files too:

```
apt-get download base-files
sudo dpkg -i base-files*.deb
```

Now try to update your package list, etc.:

```
dpkg --audit
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get check
```

Compare `ls -l /var/lib/dpkg` with the above list. If some `-old` file is not present don't worry it as it would be created with the normal usage of the system.

Comment: Thanks for response. I followed the steps as you mentioned here, but while executing **sudo dpkg -i dpkg*.deb**, I am getting an error as **dpkg: error: failed to open package info file `/usr/local/var/lib/dpkg/status' for reading: No such file or directory**

Comment: @Sambit Impossible. Can you edit your question and add the complete output?

Comment: @Sambit `ls: cannot access /usr/local/var/lib/dpkg/status: No such file or directory` is the only thing I get. `/usr/local` is not place to install dpkg files.

Comment: Same problem here, Ubuntu trying to  install in `/usr/local/` instead of in  `/var/lib/dpkg`. How to make it point to `/var/lib/dpkg`?

Comment: @bagustris download the package from the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: @Braiam, still using wget to download from ubuntu repo give me the same error when trying to install using dpkg -i: dpkg: error: `failed to open package info file `/usr/local/var/lib/dpkg/available' for reading: No such file or directory`

Comment: I solved this issue by creating directory and file: ` sudo touch /usr/local/var/log/alternatives.log`. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well `dpkg` (Debian package management system ) package provides the low-level infrastructure for handling the installation and removal of Debian software packages.So removing it was not a good idea, and you can can it back by-

Downloading the file by using `wget` :

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/dpkg_1.16.1.2ubuntu7.2.tar.bz2
```

Extract it in xxx folder.

```
tar -xvf dpkg_1.16*
cd dpkg-1.16*
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

hope it will work.

Comment: I've go through those steps and successfully installed. but again I am getting the same problem.

Comment: does ./configure failed or was successful??

Comment: Already restarted and I get the same error as mentioned in my question. Also inbuilt software like "Ubuntu Software Centre", "Update Manager" are also not working.

Comment: hey i have updated wget first commands, try the same procedure start with wget command

Comment: Now I am getting error like 'E: Could not open file /var/lib/dpkg/status - open (2: No such file or directory)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.'

Comment: getting error, **cp: cannot stat `/var/lib/dpkg/status-old': No such file or directory**. I am facing these problem because "dpkg" directory doesn't exist in my system.

Comment: I get an error: **make: No targetsspecified andnomakefilefound. Stop.**

Answer (score 1):

Recover your system from backup. You did make backups right? Backing up your system and data is critical to deal with unexpected situations such as this one (user error) and hardware failure. If you failed to create backups such as discussed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) you can attempt [data recovery.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463076/partitions-disappeared-after-power-loss-while-installing)

In future I suggest that you [backup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) on a regular basis to avoid catastrophic data loss. And I doubt you'll forget that as @Braiam said "***root + rm + -r = disaster***"