# Copy the Windows 7 files to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I was working in the Windows 7 OS previously, now i shifted to the ubuntu 14.04 version. I had important file on D && E drive of Windows 7 which i couldn't take backup. **How to recover those data in Ubutnu?**

(I had choose the only ubuntu option while installing the ubuntu)

Comment: You may also find http://askubuntu.com/questions/463076/partitions-disappeared-after-power-loss-while-installing/463094#463094 helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you chose the Delete Windows option, then there is no way to recover your files (if the files were in the same partition as the Windows install).

If you backed up the files to another partition/drive, then you can open them with Ubuntu's file manager by selecting where it is.

Comment: This isn't really helpful as the OP has indicated that no backup was done. Also saying something is impossible doesn't make it so.