# Can I recover data from lost partitions?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, data-recovery

I had Windows 7 and Windows 8 dual booted. I tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 by deleting Windows 8, but unfortunately whole hard disk wiped. Now I have only Ubuntu 14.04 installed using whole hard disk size. I'm at a loss now after losing my project data.

I had 3 NTFS partitions other than the Win 7 and Win 8 partitions.

Can I recover my data? If possible how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very long post about recovering lost partitions, which I believe can be applied to your situation.  It's worth a shot anyway...

[Partitions disappeared after power loss while installing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463076/partitions-disappeared-after-power-loss-while-installing/463094#46309)

Answer (score 0):

Data recovery is very unlikely if you are using Ubuntu for some time. There are chances that your data is overwritten and hence available to recover in laboratory conditions, but definitely not in the home environment.

Anyway you can try to rebuild partition table to get access to previous partitions. But I assume, that if you didn't backed up your project files, then you didn't have backup of partition table as well. You can try to set up new partition table that is **exactly the same as before**, but it still don't guarantee any success.

Another option is the help of some data recovery company, but such services are extremely expensive, so if your project is not a life and death matter, I would not recommend it.

Well, to sum up, the best advice:

**Make a backup of your important files. Always.**

Comment: I didn't use Ubuntu at all, neither installed anything. Once I realized what has happened, I didn't do anything on the hard disk. All I have done till now is replacing everything with Ubuntu 14.04