# Dual boot win7 ubuntu: win7 gone！

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

Recently I installed Ubuntu 64 after Win7 64. I used 'Try Ubuntu' to set the disk partition with ext4 and swap.
But after I installed the Ubuntu, my windows system is gone. Even I used Boot-repair, I could not find the partition that I installed Win7. Can anyone help?

I want to find my data under Win7. Because it seems that the Win7 with the UEFI partition have been erased!

Comment: welcome to askUbuntu! Please help us help you by booting Ubuntu opening a terminal and providing the output of the command 'sudo fdisk -l` or if you have a GPT partition structure the command 'gdisk -l /dev/sda

Comment: You may also find this helpful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/463076/partitions-disappeared-after-power-loss-while-installing/

Comment: @ElderGeek Thank you. I remember that I installed twice, at the second time I chose 'erase installed Ubuntu'. Does this influence? Moreover, I have problem with '/init: line 7: can't open /dev/sr0: No medium found' when installing Ubuntu. And I used 'break debug' at boot. Is this the reason that my disk has been erased? Thanks!

Comment: These are different questions and answers should be searched for and/or asked separately. The reason I'm asking for the output of fdisk or gdisk (above) is it will help us determine the state of the drive. You say you used Boot-repair. Please provide the URL of your boot repair report. This will also contain the information I seek so that we can help you. Thank you.

Comment: @Aaron, give us some detail what you did get to where you are now. Some will be able to help you. Did you follow a specific tutorial. If so which one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases the lost data still can be recovered. Don't panic. :)

Launch GParted and check if there are any NTFS partitions on your primary hard disk. If so, you probably can access your data (NTFS partitions are accessible from Ubuntu by default).

If your Windows partitions (NTFS) are lost, read the following article: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery