# Laptop Content Wiped

Tags: data-recovery, lenovo, vmware

I am kinda desperate and any help will be appreciated.
I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on a Lenovo T530i, and my HDD was almost full.

I planned to buy an external HDD this week end and transfer some data, but then as I was working I got a notification from VMWare that the host OS had 3 gb free only and that it will shutdown, so I switched off my VMWare player and to find out that my whole computer has been wiped out, can't find a single data anywhere.

Is there a way to retrieve my data as this is really a big loss for me.

Regards,

### lsblk command:

```
davwise@davwise-ThinkPad-T530:~$ lsblk

NAME                         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                            8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk 
├─sda1                         8:1    0   243M  0 part /boot 
├─sda2                         8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5                         8:5    0 465,5G  0 part 
  ├─ubuntu--vg-root (dm-0)   252:0    0 457,8G  0 lvm  /
  └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 (dm-1) 252:1    0   7,7G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sr0                           11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

### mount command:

```
davwise@davwise-ThinkPad-T530:~$ mount
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext2 (rw)
rpc_pipefs on /run/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
vmware-vmblock on /run/vmblock-fuse type fuse.vmware-vmblock (rw,nosuid,nodev,default_permissions,allow_other)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=davwise)
```

### cat /etc/fstab command:

```
davwise@davwise-ThinkPad-T530:~$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /   ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation 
# UUID=3be6bedc-7d14-458b-b075-7845025e4e4a /boot  ext2    defaults        0       2
# /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none   swap    sw              0       0
```

**Edit: Result of testdisk**
[image: Testdisk Result]

Comment: This appears to be a VMware problem. You might find this useful: www.vmware.com/files/pdf/vmfs-best-practices-wp.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do is clone an image of the drive so that you have a copy in case something more goes horribly wrong. You might want to start [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463076/partitions-disappeared-after-power-loss-while-installing/463094#463094)

Based on your current /etc/fstab, It looks like the partition you want to run  testdisk on is /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root - Refer to the linked related answer for detail and adjust your actions accordingly. If something is unclear, comment and I'll try to clear it up.

Answer (score 0):

I really wonder how did the data get wiped off all of sudden.

You can try DataRecovery tool known as PhotoRec it will recover every deleted file.

Just type photorec in terminal as a root user and select the Hard Disk. You can see an option to recover data based on file types like mp3, mp4, jpeg etc choose required files.

This will help.

Photorec is a part of Testdisk software, you can download it [here](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download).