# Can't Boot Window7 at grub2 menu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on the same partition as windows 7. I shrunk the win7 partition expecting that that will allow me to install Ubuntu ( which it did ).  When I start up my computer it goes to my HP probook start up screen where you can access your BIOS, then next is the Grub2 menu. Problem is that windows 7 does not show on the grub.

For the past 2 days I have been reading solutions and tried

```
sudo update-grub2
```

- Also tried boot-repair
- Manually adding a menu entry for windows 7
- Creating a systems repair disc, but I am unable to get a windows 7 system image. And when I enter the product key, from the Microsoft recovery website, it says that there is a problem with the network.

The windows partition still doesn't show. Does anyone have any Idea what might have happened and how I can fix it?

**EDIT:**

I Followed this written process to shrink a partition https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg309169.aspx, And in the unallocated space created is where I installed Ubuntu. However, I did not create a new partition from the unallocated space, just installed Ubuntu there.

Also every time I boot my pc and login to Ubuntu I get a notification saying that my hard disk memory is full.

From the two reasons above I believe that windows 7 still exists.

gparted looks like this: http://postimg.org/image/8pli3mhc5/

Comment: On the same partition? How does that work? Do you mean on the same harddrive?

Comment: @PeterNerlich Sadly, since the Windows partition doesn't show, I think "same partition" is exactly what was meant. (AKA Windows overwritten.) although admittedly this is quite unclear as the question doesn't indicate where the partition is expected to be seen, nor how it's expected to be seen.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Please help us help you by [edit]ing your question and including more detail on exactly what you mean by "The windows partition doesn't show". Thank you!

Comment: Put another way: From what you have posted, we are unable to determine if Windows still exists on your hard drive.  Can you provide any evidence that it still does?

Comment: @Elder Geek, yes the same partition was meant. I do believe I have over written Windows, so what do I ? or do you want me to do anything for confirmation?

Comment: Based on your edit I would say that it's likely that the installer did the partitioning for you. To verify, boot from the live (installation) media that you used to install, and either run gparted and provide us a link to a screen shot (uploaded to imgur.com) or drop to a terminal with CTRL-T and issue the command `sudo fdisk -l` and copy and paste the output into your question via [edit]. thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Scratch that. Missed the other comments. You may be able to recover something though. This has worked for others in a similar situation. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/463076/partitions-disappeared-after-power-loss-while-installing/463094#463094

Answer (score 0):

Try to press f9 Immediately on boot...It would take you to the EFI Bios boot screen, See if "OS Boot Manager" is an option there, and if it boots.
There is also the option of Manually selecting an EFI file Use it to browse the EFI System Partition to locate the EFI files with the .EFI extension and try to boot from it.

Answer (score 0):

Use your Ubuntu CD Live and launch a terminal console where you are going to type these commands:

```
sudo su [Enter]
gparted [Enter]
```

Take a picture of **gparted** and post the link to the image (for privileges reasons in this forum you can not include an image directly in your post). We will see if you still have a Windows 7 partition in your hard disk drive. If you have it, I will edit my post to point out how you can manually adding a menu entry for windows 7.

Comment: And how do I get the link to my picture? do I have to post it on the web or something? P.S I got the gparted to open and show the partitions. @xunilk

Comment: @RasinBreadIsAwesome You can use this web: http://postimage.org/index.php?lang=english

Comment: Here it is http://postimg.org/image/8pli3mhc5/ - @xunilk

Comment: Bad news. You have no Windows or Ubuntu.

Comment: If your sda4 partition is for recovery (I don't know that) you can get your Windows again.

Comment: well it sda4,which is HP-TOOLS, has a folder called Hewlette-Packard -> BIOS and sparekey folders.