# How do I recover NTFS partition table ?

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, ntfs, testdisk

I have a hard disk formatted to NTFS partition type. I accidentaly wrote a ufs image (1 GB onto it). It has lots of important data . Can I recover the partition table and the data ? If yes, then how should I go about it ?

I have seen several questions regarding the same kind of problems which recommend test disk , but will test disk or some other application work in this case ?

Comment: Quite possibly. Try http://askubuntu.com/questions/463076/partitions-disappeared-after-power-loss-while-installing/463094#463094. Different case but the same approach can be used.