# Newly installed Ubuntu does not see other hard drive

Tags: 14.04, data-recovery

I am entirely new to Ubuntu. I installed v14.04 LTS on the C drive of a functional PC which has a working D drive containing data. Ubuntu does not recognise it.  I have looked at similar requests for help but have not yet succeeded in solving the problem. My partitions search produced this:

```
   11        0    1048575 sr0
      11        1    1048575 sr1
       8        0  312571224 sda
       8        1  309686272 sda1
       8        2          1 sda2
       8        5    2882560 sda5
```

What does this tell me and what can I do, please?

The result of sudo fdisk -l was:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000c2ac6

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   619374591   309686272   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       619376638   625141759     2882561    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       619376640   625141759     2882560   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

SOLVED after a fashion. There was no power to the drive! Presumably dislodged by replacing case. Ubuntu did not read it when powered up, so loaded drive into a dock on a Windows PC, reformatted it, Ubuntu now reads it OK.
Will soon have to ask a new question about how to create a home network sharing Ubuntu and Windows. If only instructions were clear for us oldies! Many thanks for your help on this one.

Comment: What is the output of: sudo fdisk -l

Comment: It shows one hard-drive `sda` with about 160GB capacity. The drive is divided in three partitions. `sda1` has a size of about 158.5GB. `sda2` seems to be an extended partition which contains `sda5`. `sda5` has a size of about 1.5GB. Use another command to show drives. Run `sudo fdisk -l` in terminal and paste output into your question to be sure, I don't know which command you did use.

Comment: If you had a second physical drive it would show up in your fdisk output as /dev/sdb since this is not the case I can only conclude that your "D" drive was actually a partition rather than a physical drive and you mistakenly overwrote it when you installed. You are likely to be able to recover much of the data with ubuntu however. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu and http://askubuntu.com/questions/463076/partitions-disappeared-after-power-loss-while-installing