# My PC gone while deleting files from USB

Tags: usb

I have a really big problem.
I wanted to delete files from USB. I searched and have found a link did it on terminal something like

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda1 bc = 4MG
```

and then my PC just frozen I shut it down. Now My PC can't turn on

Please help me

Comment: `sda` usually is the drive where the OS is installed. And the command you used, `dd` has the nickname of "disk destroyer" for a reason: It doesn't ask for confirmation, it doesn't take prisoners. You system was **wiped out** with that single command.

Comment: So how can I fix it please help

Comment: You have to reinstall.

Comment: Before you reinstall, even before you do anything else with the internal drive, you should try to recover the important files.  See this link with tips how to repair a file system and/or recover files even without a file system, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986

Comment: Never run any command just because it is written somewhere. Before running it, have a look in man page to see what is the command for.

Comment: You've accidentally wiped out your MBR, partitiion table and a little more, but much of your data should still be recoverable. I answered a similar question [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/463094/225694)

Answer (score 2):

There is a high probability that /dev/sda1 (/dev/sda being first hard disk) was your root partition and you have overwritten first 4MB of it with random data. You will have to reinstall Ubuntu on your system. before doing this. I recommend that you get an bootable USB with one of the Ubuntu Rescue distribution and try to salvage the data from the root partition. You will need an external hard disk drive to save the salvaged data.

Overview of the rescue linux OSs:

https://opensource.com/life/15/2/five-specialized-linux-distributions-computer-repair

Comment: Actually, you can accomplish the task with the Ubuntu installation media. No "Rescue OS" is required. See [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/463094/225694)