# I set windows partition as active, now loads into grub rescue

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, grubrescue

I have an SSD with 3 partitions, the first for windows 10 and the other two for ubuntu 16.04 (one for root and the other for home). I had installed windows 10 first, then ubuntu 16.04, and installed the grub loader on the ssd.

Later, when I booted into windows 10, I accidentally set the windows partition as active, and noticed that a partition disappeared (the one with root). When I restarted my computer I go into grub rescue.

I ran the command "ls", and it listed a bunch of partitions. When I ran the command "set", the prefix and root were a partition that wasn't listed in ls. So I'm guessing a partition was deleted (probably the ubuntu root one).

I'm stuck in grub rescue. How do I recover my pc?

Comment: Can you boot from. a live USB drive and see if your partition is still accessible?

Comment: You can recover deleted partitions  by using `testdisk`  Here's a related post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/463076/partitions-disappeared-after-power-loss-while-installing

Comment: @AndroidDev yea, I was able to boot from a live USB into ubuntu and I used the command sudo lsblk to list the partitions. unfortunately it seems like both home and root partitions are gone.  All I have is a partition for windows 10 and a partition for swap (I forgot to mention that)

Comment: Can you check what Gparted shows?

Comment: @ElderGeek I booted from a live USB and pressed "try ubuntu without installing" but it doesn't seem to have testdisk.. If I try to install I get "E: unable to locate testdisk"

Comment: @AndroidDev I'm trying to use Gparted as mentioned here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery
but I'm not sure how to use the rescue function. I entered approximate values for the start and end, but nothing happens. it just goes to the next line (parted).

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't get it to work. I had installed Ubuntu only a few days ago, so it's not a big deal for me to reinstall it. That's what I did. For the time being, I'm not going to mess around with anything related to the partitions.