# Seagate RAID 0 mount on Ubuntu

Tags: mount, raid

I'm going to try mounting my Seagate NAS 220 in Ubuntu since it wont boot anymore and I can't communicate with the Seagate NAS anymore. The drives should be ok.

Is this a software RAID or do i need to make the RAID in BIOS first?

I think the file system id ext3 but I'm not 100% sure.

I have installed the drives in an Ubuntu machine and I want to mount them if it's possible

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 47AC4902-6A51-42B0-B05D-3708D82E8FF9

Device       Start        End    Sectors    Size Type
/dev/sda1   195312    2283203    2087892 1019.5M Linux RAID
/dev/sda2  2283204    4373046    2089843 1020.4M Linux RAID
/dev/sda3  4373047    5416015    1042969  509.3M Linux RAID
/dev/sda4  5416016 3906832031 3901416016    1.8T Linux RAID

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/sdb: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: FD12324A-BD14-43C2-A94D-5C99BC43449C

Device       Start        End    Sectors    Size Type
/dev/sdb1   195312    2283203    2087892 1019.5M Linux RAID
/dev/sdb2  2283204    4373046    2089843 1020.4M Linux RAID
/dev/sdb3  4373047    5416015    1042969  509.3M Linux RAID
/dev/sdb4  5416016 3906832031 3901416016    1.8T Linux RAID

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/sdc: 58.4 GiB, 62742792192 bytes, 122544516 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x54d9f748

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1  *     2048 122544127 122542080 58.4G 83 Linux
```

I tried using mdadm using the following command.

```
$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdb4
/dev/sdb4:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : bc1ea9fb:199456cd:b13d59a4:6ef0d903
           Name : 3
  Creation Time : Fri Feb 10 18:12:52 2012
     Raid Level : raid0
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 3901416000 (1860.34 GiB 1997.52 GB)
    Data Offset : 16 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : 5ab819f7:a0982ebb:5b6b0d31:e8cebe50

    Update Time : Thu Jul  6 10:57:09 2017
       Checksum : df91edc7 - correct
         Events : 653

     Chunk Size : 64K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

$ sudo mdadm -A -R /dev/md9 /dev/sdb4
mdadm: /dev/sdb4 is busy - skipping
```

Answer (score 2):

As referred to in [the manual](http://www.seagate.com/files/www-content/about/newsroom/media-kits/_shared/images/BlackArmorNAS220UserGuide.pdf) on page 40, when the [system status is blinking blue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/935404/seagegate-raid-0-mount-with-ubuntu/935801#comment1481795_935408), the RAID array is rebuilding. This can take several hours. I would recommend putting the drives back where they came from and allowing the rebuild process to complete. If you did indeed utilize RAID0 (striping) rather than the default RAID1 you may be out of luck as there's no fault tolerance in RAID0. You might be able to recover some files by [utilizing testdisk.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463076/partitions-disappeared-after-power-loss-while-installing)

Comment: i already tried leaving it on for 14 hours stil just blinking

Comment: Perhaps Seagate Technical support: 1 (800) 732-4283 can provide some insights. As RAID 0 (striping)  has no fault tolerance you are likely fighting a losing battle. You might be able to recover some files by [utilizing testdisk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463076/partitions-disappeared-after-power-loss-while-installing)

Comment: ive already talked to them, they cant help me so my only chance is to get it mounted in linux

Comment: It's unclear (at least to me) what you are attempting to accomplish with `sudo mdadm -A -R /dev/md9 /dev/sdb4` Are you attempting to assemble and start the array without /dev/sda4 (which in RAID 0 contains the other 1/2 of your data)? You might wish to review http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/mdadm.8.html

Answer (score 0):

The [Seagate BlackArmor® NAS 220](http://www.seagate.com/files/www-content/about/newsroom/media-kits/_shared/images/BlackArmorNAS220UserGuide.pdf) is a [Network-attached Storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage) standalone device meant to be accessed from the network.

The RAID arrangement is managed by the device itself. The users don't need to deal with the RAID configuration in hardware/OS like they would have to with a physically attached array.

Comment: the problem is it keeps blinking blue and never starts up. its the same problem as this guy https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/260256-black-armor-440-stuck-at-booting. i have taken the drives out and moved them into my ubuntu machine where i wanna mount them now to recover the data.

Comment: *the problem is it nerver boots up it keeps blinking within the startup.* What's blinking? Ubuntu? If it's Ubuntu, it has nothing to do with the NAS and the question as it stands is the opposite of smart. If it's the NAS not booting for some reason, whatever reason, it s off topic.

Comment: its not off topic im not here to get help about the NAS i have moved the drives into a ubuntu machine to mount the raid there.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/6V1y0wV.png     here is what fdisk -l looks like any help for mounting the raid. thank you

Comment: @SteffenHalvorsen Please edit the output of fdisk into your question. Use text please. Are you certain you changed the RAID configuration from the default RAID 1 to RAID 0?

Comment: http://freedatarecovery.us/ this guy mounted my raid with no problem when you guys wont help.