# Ubuntu 17.10 is not booting due to hard disk being full of recovered files

Tags: 17.10, virtualization, data-recovery

I'm new to Ubuntu.

Yesterday I accidentally deleted my Virtual Machine Windows 7 (32 bit) in VirtualBox on host Ubuntu 17.10. After that I tried to recover using Testdisk. It's not recovered and another method tried using Photorec it recovered some files but not finished because my hard disk storage not enough. So I stopped after my notebook little bit hangs so that's why Restarted bot right now it's showing

```
dev/sda2 /30498816 /30457001 files, 121959007 /121965056 blocks
```

Comment: What’s your question? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Some tips: Keep backups, use a trash can / recycle bin instead of straight delete, testdisk should see & recover files and their names, photorec doesn't recover names or folders (everything's in a "big messy pile"). And recovering deleted files onto the same partition will just overwrite anything not yet recovered. Tried freeing some space to get it to boot again?

Comment: Never attempt data recovery to the same partition. You should always work on an image or clone of the drive as [discussed here](https://askubuntu.com/a/463094/225694)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot your system and tap `Esc` after the BIOS screen to enter the GRUB menu, then press `e` to edit and append `init=/bin/bash` to the line starting with `linux`. Press `Ctrl+x` to boot, log in, and make your filesystem writable via `mount -oremount,rw /`. Navigate to the folder where the recovered files are and delete them as needed.

Alternatively, you can boot a live CD/USB and delete your recovered files from the live session after mounting your disk.