# I tried dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 and accidentally deleted Windows

Tags: dual-boot

I have two disks in my laptop, one is a 1TB HDD and one is a 512GB SSD. I had Windows 10 on the HDD and wanted to install Ubuntu on the SSD. As I did that my HDD drive got formatted and is now called DATA and looks like this.

[image: DATA disk]

I want to install Windows back on it but I'm worried that it will end up messing up my Ubuntu installation. How do I handle this properly?

Comment: How big is the partition?  It may just be mounting the boot partition that sits at the beginning of your HDD (primary boot drive, i'm assuming) but leaving Windows alone.  Generally you don't just accidentally format the HDD, in the sense that there are several questions/warnings you have to deliberately pass before reformatting the entire drive.

Comment: The partition takes up the entire 1TB HDD. I don't this it's just leaving Windows alone, it says the whole disk is almost empty, aside from the files you can see in the folder. If i boot Windows from the Grub it takes me straight to a safe boot and if I try troubleshooting and repairing Windows it just resets back to the beginning of the safe boot. If I were to install Windows on this disk would it in any way mess up Ubuntu?

Comment: It looks like you installed the Windows installer to your drive, not to a flash drive. And that erased entire hard drive.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Similar problem [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463076/partitions-disappeared-after-power-loss-while-installing) with a different cause but the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can instead use the testdisk tool as described [here](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step), maybe you can recover your old Windows with it.

I had such a case but I deleted Ubuntu rather than windows, the tool helped me to restore all data without any problem because I didn't write data on that disk after the accident.