# Why does removing Xinerama remove so many packages?

Tags: 14.04, dependencies, xinerama

Here's my output below. Please explain why it removes so many packages. I only have one monitor. I, for example, still need Gnome icons. What the h*ll does that have to do with Xinerama? As far as the strange errors, please note that this is Windows Linux Subsystem, so things like dbus are not available.

```
sudo apt remove xinerama*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libxcb-xinerama0' for regex 'xinerama*'
Note, selecting 'x11proto-xinerama-dev' for regex 'xinerama*'
Note, selecting 'libxinerama1-dbg' for regex 'xinerama*'
Note, selecting 'libxcb-xinerama0-dbg' for regex 'xinerama*'
Note, selecting 'libxcb-xinerama0-dev' for regex 'xinerama*'
Note, selecting 'libxinerama1' for regex 'xinerama*'
Note, selecting 'libxinerama-dev' for regex 'xinerama*'
Package 'libxcb-xinerama0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libxcb-xinerama0-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libxcb-xinerama0-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libxinerama1-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  aspell aspell-en dictionaries-common emacsen-common enchant
  fp-compiler-2.6.2 fp-units-base-2.6.2 fp-units-fcl-2.6.2 fp-units-rtl-2.6.2
  fp-utils-2.6.2 gdebi-core gir1.2-atk-1.0 gir1.2-atspi-2.0 gir1.2-freedesktop
  gir1.2-gck-1 gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0
  gir1.2-pango-1.0 gir1.2-spice-client-glib-2.0 gnome-accessibility-themes
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-x
  hunspell-en-us libaa1 libaspell15 libasyncns0 libatk-bridge2.0-dev
  libatk1.0-dev libatspi2.0-dev libavc1394-0 libcaca0
  libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcairo2-dev libcanberra0 libcdparanoia0
  libdbus-1-dev libdbus-glib-1-dev libdv4 libenchant1c2a libexpat1-dev
  libflac8 libfm-data libfm-extra4 libfm-gtk-data libfm4 libfontconfig1-dev
  libfreetype6-dev libgck-1-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libgee-0.8-2 libgeoclue0
  libglu1-mesa libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0
  libgstreamer1.0-0 libharfbuzz-dev libharfbuzz-gobject0 libharfbuzz-icu0
  libhunspell-1.3-0 libice-dev libiec61883-0 libjack-jackd2-0
  libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0-dbg
  libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-dev libjpeg-progs libjpeg-turbo-progs libnotify4
  libogg0 libopus0 liborc-0.4-0 libp11-kit-dev libpango1.0-dev libperl5.20
  libpixman-1-dev libpng12-dev libpthread-stubs0-dev libpulse-mainloop-glib0
  libpulse0 libraw1394-11 libshout3 libsm-dev libsndfile1 libspeex1
  libspice-client-glib-2.0-8 libspice-protocol-dev libspice-server1 libssl-dev
  libssl-doc libtag1-vanilla libtag1c2a libtasn1-6-dev libtasn1-bin libtcl8.6
  libtheora0 libusbredirhost1 libusbredirparser1 libv4l-0 libv4lconvert0
  libvisual-0.4-0 libvisual-0.4-plugins libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2
  libvorbisfile3 libwavpack1 libwayland-dev libwayland-server0 libwebp5
  libwebpmux1 libwhoopsie-preferences0 libwhoopsie0 libx11-dev libx11-doc
  libxau-dev libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb1-dev libxcomposite-dev
  libxcursor-dev libxdamage-dev libxdmcp-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev
  libxft-dev libxi-dev libxkbcommon-dev libxrandr-dev libxrender-dev
  libxslt1.1 libxtst-dev python-imaging python-pil python-support
  spice-client-glib-usb-acl-helper whoopsie-preferences x11proto-composite-dev
  x11proto-core-dev x11proto-damage-dev x11proto-fixes-dev x11proto-input-dev
  x11proto-kb-dev x11proto-randr-dev x11proto-record-dev x11proto-render-dev
  x11proto-xext-dev xchat-common xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  pinentry-curses
Suggested packages:
  pinentry-doc
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  activity-log-manager adwaita-icon-theme feh fp-units-gtk-2.6.2 gcr gdebi
  gir1.2-gcr-3 gir1.2-gtk-2.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-spice-client-gtk-2.0
  gir1.2-vte-2.90 gir1.2-webkit-1.0 gir1.2-webkit-3.0 gksu gnome-icon-theme
  gnome-icon-theme-extras gnome-icon-theme-full gnome-icon-theme-nuovo
  gnome-icon-theme-suede gnome-icon-theme-symbolic gnome-keyring
  gnome-themes-standard gnome-themes-standard-data gtk-theme-switch
  gtk2-engines-murrine gtk2-engines-pixbuf gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-daemons
  libcanberra-gtk3-0 libcanberra-gtk3-module libfm-gtk4 libfm-modules
  libgcr-3-dev libgcr-ui-3-1 libgksu2-0 libglade2-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin
  libgtk-3-common libgtk-3-dev libgtk2-perl libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin
  libgtk2.0-dev libobrender29 libobt2 librsvg2-bin libsexy2
  libspice-client-glib-2.0-dev libspice-client-gtk-2.0-4
  libspice-client-gtk-2.0-dev libspice-server-dev libunity-control-center1
  libvte-2.90-9 libwebkit-dev libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0-dbg
  libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-0-dbg libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev
  libwebkitgtk-dev libxinerama-dev libxinerama1 murrine-themes
  notification-daemon obconf obmenu oboinus openbox openbox-menu pcmanfm
  pinentry-gtk2 policykit-1-gnome python-glade2 python-gtk2 shimmer-themes
  synaptic tint2 x11-utils x11proto-xinerama-dev xchat zeitgeist
  zeitgeist-datahub zeitgeist-explorer
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  pinentry-curses
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 85 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 27.0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,200 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe pinentry-curses amd64 0.8.3-1ubuntu1 [27.0 kB]
Fetched 27.0 kB in 0s (58.8 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 135579 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing activity-log-manager (0.9.7-0ubuntu14.1) ...
Removing gnome-keyring (3.10.1-1ubuntu4.3) .........................................................................]
Removing gcr (3.14.0-2) ............................................................................................]
Removing notification-daemon (0.7.6-1) .............................................................................]
Removing libgcr-3-dev (3.14.0-2) ...................................................................................]
Removing gir1.2-gcr-3 (3.14.0-2) ...................................................................................]
Removing gnome-themes-standard:amd64 (3.14.2.2-1) ..................................................................]
Removing gnome-themes-standard-data (3.14.2.2-1) ...................................................................]
Removing oboinus (2.3-1) ...........................................................................................]
Removing feh (2.9.3-1) ...##........................................................................................]
Removing fp-units-gtk-2.6.2 (2.6.2-8) ..............................................................................]
Removing gdebi (0.9.5.3ubuntu2) ....................................................................................]
Removing libspice-client-gtk-2.0-dev (0.25-1+b1) ...................................................................]
Removing gir1.2-spice-client-gtk-2.0 (0.25-1+b1) ...................................................................]
Removing libwebkit-dev (2.4.10-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...................................................................]
Removing libwebkitgtk-dev (2.4.10-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ................................................................]
Removing libgtk2.0-dev (2.24.25-3+deb8u1) ..........................................................................]
Removing libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev (2.4.10-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ............................................................]
Removing libgtk-3-dev:amd64 (3.14.5-1+deb8u1) ......................................................................]
Removing gir1.2-vte-2.90 (1:0.34.9-1ubuntu2) .......................................................................]
Removing gir1.2-webkit-1.0 (2.4.10-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...............................................................]
Removing gir1.2-webkit-3.0 (2.4.10-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...............................................................]
Removing gksu (2.0.2-6ubuntu2) ...#########.........................................................................]
Removing gnome-icon-theme-extras (3.12.0-1ubuntu1) .................................................................]
Removing gnome-icon-theme-nuovo (0.5-4.1) ..........................................................................]
Removing gnome-icon-theme-suede (0.2.5-1) ...#......................................................................]
Removing gnome-icon-theme-symbolic (3.10.1-1ubuntu1) ...............................................................]
Removing gtk-theme-switch (2.1.0-3) ...##########...................................................................]
Removing shimmer-themes (1.7.3-0ubuntu1) ...######..................................................................]
Removing murrine-themes (0.98.6ubuntu1) ...########.................................................................]
Removing gtk2-engines-murrine:amd64 (0.98.2-0ubuntu2) ..............................................................]
Removing gtk2-engines-pixbuf:amd64 (2.24.25-3+deb8u1) ..............................................................]
Removing gvfs-backends (1.20.3-0ubuntu1.2) ...########..............................................................]
Removing gvfs:amd64 (1.20.3-0ubuntu1.2) ...#############............................................................]
Removing gvfs-daemons (1.20.3-0ubuntu1.2) ...############...........................................................]
Removing libcanberra-gtk3-module:amd64 (0.30-0ubuntu3) .............................................................]
Removing pcmanfm (1.2.0-1) ...#############################.........................................................]
Removing libfm-gtk4 (1.2.0-1ubuntu2) ...####################........................................................]
Removing libfm-modules (1.2.0-1ubuntu2) ...##################.......................................................]
Removing libgcr-ui-3-1:amd64 (3.14.0-2) ...####################.....................................................]
Removing libgksu2-0 (2.0.13~pre1-6ubuntu4) ...##################....................................................]
Removing obmenu (1.0-2+nmu1) ...#################################...................................................]
Removing python-glade2 (2.24.0-3ubuntu3) ...######################..................................................]
Removing libglade2-0:amd64 (1:2.6.4-2) ...#########################.................................................]
Removing libgtk2-perl (2:1.2492-4) ...#############################.................................................]
Removing xchat (2.8.8-7.3) ...#######################################...............................................]
Removing libgtk2.0-bin (2.24.25-3+deb8u1) ...##########################.............................................]
Removing openbox-menu (0.5.1-2) ...#####################################............................................]
Removing openbox (3.5.2-8) ...##########################################............................................]
Removing obconf (1:2.0.4+git20130908-2) ...###############################..........................................]
Removing libobrender29 (3.5.2-8) ...#######################################.........................................]
Removing libobt2 (3.5.2-8) ...#############################################.........................................]
Removing librsvg2-bin (2.40.2-1) ...#########################################.......................................]
Removing libsexy2 (0.1.11-2ubuntu1) ...#######################################......................................]
Removing libspice-client-glib-2.0-dev (0.25-1+b1) ...###########################....................................]
Removing libspice-client-gtk-2.0-4:amd64 (0.25-1+b1) ...########################....................................]
Removing libspice-server-dev (0.12.5-1+deb8u3) ...###############################...................................]
Removing libunity-control-center1 (14.04.3+14.04.20150916-0ubuntu1) ...###########..................................]
Removing synaptic (0.81.1ubuntu1) ...##############################################.................................]
Removing libvte-2.90-9 (1:0.34.9-1ubuntu2) ...#######################################...............................]
Removing libwebkitgtk-1.0-0-dbg:amd64 (2.4.10-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...###################..............................]
Removing libwebkitgtk-1.0-0:amd64 (2.4.10-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...########################.............................]
Removing libwebkitgtk-3.0-0-dbg:amd64 (2.4.10-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...#####################............................]
Removing libwebkitgtk-3.0-0:amd64 (2.4.10-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...##########################...........................]
Removing libxinerama-dev:amd64 (2:1.1.3-1+b1) ...#########################################..........................]
Removing tint2 (0.11+svn20121014-1) ...#####################################################........................]
Removing x11-utils (7.7+1) ...###############################################################.......................]
Removing libcanberra-gtk3-0:amd64 (0.30-2.1) ...##############################################......................]
Removing gir1.2-gtk-2.0 (2.24.25-3+deb8u1) ...#################################################.....................]
Removing adwaita-icon-theme (3.14.0-2) ...######################################################....................]
Removing gnome-icon-theme-full (3.10.0-0ubuntu2) ...#############################################...................]
dpkg: warning: while removing gnome-icon-theme-full, directory '/usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable/places' not empty so not removed
Removing gnome-icon-theme (3.10.0-0ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: warning: while removing gnome-icon-theme, directory '/usr/share/icons/gnome' not empty so not removed.........]
Removing libgtk-3-bin (3.10.8-0ubuntu1.6) ...
Removing 'diversion of /usr/sbin/update-icon-caches to /usr/sbin/update-icon-caches.gtk2 by libgtk-3-bin'
Removing 'diversion of /usr/share/man/man8/update-icon-caches.8.gz to /usr/share/man/man8/update-icon-caches.gtk2.8.gz by libgtk-3-bin'
dpkg: libxinerama1:amd64: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:#################...............]
 libgtk-3-0:amd64 depends on libxinerama1.
 libgtk2.0-0:amd64 depends on libxinerama1.

Removing libxinerama1:amd64 (2:1.1.3-1+b1) ...
dpkg: libgtk-3-0:amd64: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:####################..............]
 policykit-1-gnome depends on libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.0.0).
 zeitgeist-datahub depends on libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.0.0).
 gir1.2-gtk-3.0:amd64 depends on libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.13.7).

Removing libgtk-3-0:amd64 (3.14.5-1+deb8u1) ...
dpkg: gir1.2-gtk-3.0:amd64: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:#################.............]
 zeitgeist-explorer depends on gir1.2-gtk-3.0.

Removing gir1.2-gtk-3.0:amd64 (3.14.5-1+deb8u1) ...
Removing libgtk-3-common (3.14.5-1+deb8u1) ...##########################################################............]
dpkg: libgtk2.0-0:amd64: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:######################...........]
 python-gtk2 depends on libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0).
 pinentry-gtk2 depends on libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.10.0).

Removing libgtk2.0-0:amd64 (2.24.25-3+deb8u1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...####################################################.........]
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18+deb8u6) ...
Processing triggers for gconf2 (3.2.6-0ubuntu2) ...

(gconftool-2:5423): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.42.1-1+b1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libglib2.0-0:amd64.postinst: line 9:  5437 Aborted                 (core dumped) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/gio-querymodules $dirs
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.3-1) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.46ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for python-support (1.0.15) ...
Processing triggers for doc-base (0.10.5) ...
Possible precedence issue with control flow operator at /usr/share/perl5/Debian/DocBase/DB.pm line 101.
Processing 1 removed doc-base file...
Registering documents with scrollkeeper...
Selecting previously unselected package pinentry-curses.
(Reading database ... 120636 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../pinentry-curses_0.8.3-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pinentry-curses (0.8.3-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...##############################################################........]
(Reading database ... 120644 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing policykit-1-gnome (0.105-1ubuntu4) ...
Removing python-gtk2 (2.24.0-3ubuntu3) ...###################################################################.......]
Removing x11proto-xinerama-dev (1.2.1-2) ...##################################################################......]
Removing zeitgeist-explorer (0.2-1) ...########################################################################.....]
Removing zeitgeist (0.9.14-0ubuntu4.1) ...######################################################################....]
Removing zeitgeist-datahub (0.9.14-0ubuntu4.1) ...###############################################################...]
dpkg: pinentry-gtk2: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:####################################.]
 gnupg-agent depends on pinentry-gtk2 | pinentry-curses | pinentry; however:
  Package pinentry-gtk2 is to be removed.
  Package pinentry-curses is not configured yet.
  Package pinentry is not installed.
  Package pinentry-curses which provides pinentry is not configured yet.
  Package pinentry-gtk2 which provides pinentry is to be removed.
 gnupg-agent depends on pinentry-gtk2 | pinentry-curses | pinentry; however:
  Package pinentry-gtk2 is to be removed.
  Package pinentry-curses is not configured yet.
  Package pinentry is not installed.
  Package pinentry-curses which provides pinentry is not configured yet.
  Package pinentry-gtk2 which provides pinentry is to be removed.

Removing pinentry-gtk2 (0.8.3-2) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...#############################################################]
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Setting up pinentry-curses (0.8.3-1ubuntu1) ...
```

Comment: You need to check what a * does when using with apt. 1 thing it is NOT is a wildcard...

Comment: same http://askubuntu.com/questions/210976/apt-get-remove-with-wildcard-removed-way-more-than-expected-why

Answer (score 0):

Libxinerama1 was deleted. It has the word "xinerama" in it so it was deleted with your *, in the future you really shouldn't use * for the removal of anything. Because libxinerama1 is not a xinerama package. It's the X11 interface to Xinerama, and it's installed by default. Libgtk-3-0, the entire library for GTK3 (the current version of GTK), is dependent on it. GTK is a toolkit for the X11 windows system which gnome and many other desktop environments use to build all their applications. Everything that depended on GTK was broken or removed (hopefully you didn't autoremove) and gnome was removed. So basically you lost your whole desktop environment. I'm hoping you managed to fix it? Just reinstall libxinerama1 and then reinstall gnome.

Comment: Please, it is not a wildcard; it is a regex.

Comment: First, I do appreciate your answer.

If I don't have Xinerama, why does X11 or X or Xorg need the extension? I realize the Ubuntu packages can't have an if-then-else statement for every dependency, I just don't know why package management has gone from only install if it's really needed or requested to install it because it might be needed. On the other hand, all those possible dependencies uninstall everything that might be related because it might be needed.

I think I really want to ask the people at Ubuntu who make these decisions, but I don't see a reasonable way to ask them directly.

Comment: Wikipedia seems to think it's called a wildcard, but you're probably right considering the bash output. Anyway What matters is it deleted everything with those characters in it.

Comment: Well you don't need it in the sense of you need to use the package if you don't have xinerama, but the package is an essential package for GTK so you need it if you don't want to manage your own dependencies and compile packages from the source. (and you don't) This isn't ubuntu's fault, the same thing happens on my debian which ubuntu is based off of. It isn't deb's fault either. It's the GTK people who made it a dependency. :P

Comment: Oh, and is your desktop environment working?

Comment: I did a similar thing recently when I was deleting gnome. http://askubuntu.com/questions/824686/i-accidentally-deleted-my-de-then-broke-dpkg Deleting gnome deleted some things used by MATE such as gnome-keyring, so I wound up with no desktop environment at all. In the FOSS world developers freely repurpose things originally made for other projects, and deleting A may delete B if both A and B use C. Sometimes you have to sift through each package to be sure you don't do anything you'll regret.