# How to reinstall `dpkg` Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, dpkg

Like another user, I have accidentally deleted `/var/lib/dpkg` and have poor backups. I need to reinstall `dpkg` from beginning. The solution provided to that answer is not working for me.

```
$ lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

$ ls -l /var/lib/dpkg
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 25 21:26 alternatives
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 25 21:26 info
-rw-r----- 1 root root    0 Mar 25 21:46 lock
-rw-r----- 1 root root    0 Mar 25 21:46 lock-frontend
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 25 21:26 parts
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 25 21:26 status
```

### What I've tried

**References to what I've tried:**

1. [Solution 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/383339)
2. [Solution 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/474646)
3. [Solution 3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139441)
4. [Solution 4](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1128388.html)

From (1), I was able to recover `sudo cp /var/backups/dpkg.status.0` into `/var/lib/dpkg/status`. But attempting `apt-get download dpkg` fails. So, trying the solution from link (2) above, I get partway:

```
mkdir /tmp/dpkg
cd /tmp/dpkg
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5.2_i386.deb

ar x dpkg*.deb data.tar.gz
tar xvzf data.tar.gz ./usr/bin/dpkg
cp ./usr/bin/dpkg /usr/bin/
sudo apt-get update
```

`apt-get update` gets my package lists, but then returns an error. Attempting `apt-get clean` first, as suggested in Solution 3, returns the same error. I get the same error with anything related to `apt-get` (except `apt-get clean`):

> Reading package lists... Error! 
>   E: Read error - read (21: Is a directory) 
>   E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

*Note that I am missing / have deleted file `/var/lib/dpkg/status-old`.*

Continuing to run down the rabbit hole of help resources, I found Solution 4. But when I tried `sudo dpkg -a configure`, it produces:

> dpkg: error while loading shared libraries: libselinux.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>   `

This is the same error I get from solution (1) when running `sudo dpkg -i dpkg*.deb`

Solution 4 further suggests using the program synaptic. But I cannot install since package manager is broken :(.

**Any help would be greatly appreciated!!**

Comment: I just upgraded Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04 -> 18.10 -> 19.04 instead of fixing `dpkg` within 16.04 directly

Answer (score 1):

Always try the simple step first.  Since you haven't mentioned it, try this.

In terminal type the following:

```
sudo apt install dpkg
```

Press Enter and it should work fine.

Hope that helps.  If you get an error, report back here.  We'll take it one step at a time.

Comment: Unfortunately, the same error as above `Reading package lists... Error! 
E: Read error - read (21: Is a directory) 
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.`

Comment: It may very well be that you have a pretty messed up system.  Unless you can remember all the steps you performed to get to this place, it may just be easier to do a reinstall of the operating system to get things back to normal.  You can then also consider coming up to a later LTS release.  Check Ubuntu for the correct procedure in any case.